# Conditional probability & Independent Events

Tags: probability

Im interested in learning how to determine the probability of this sample equation. Unsure how to determine the values to put into the formula when starting with a percentage.

A coach of a summer soccer team has observed a chance that has a 55% chance of winning games played on rainy days and a 60% chance of winning games on days where it is not raining. if the weather forecasts a 75% chance of rain on game day what is there probability that they will win?

Answer (score 0):

now probability of winning = (probability of raining X probability of winning while raining)+ (probability of not raining X probability of winning while not raining)
which is equal to = $(0.75*0.55 + 0.60*0.25)$
                  = 0.5625